# Visual Basic - -System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2015

I received two Visual Basic apps from another company that both functioned.  My charter is to get them both working. I got the first one working by creating a new ADO connection in VS 2008, then copied the files to the app and it works.  I'm using VS 2015 for my work.  Both apps are .NET 4.0 and were developed in VS2010.

The second app I have not been able to get to work.  I also created a new ADO Connection the same way.  This is a different database than the other app.

Let me add that I got the scripts for creating and loading the tables along with the apps and all the DLL's.

Here is the Original Connection string (when it was on their server) for the App that I eventually got to work by recreating the ADO Connection:

```
 <add name="BF_sMaxEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/BF_sMaxModel.csdl|res://*/BF_sMaxModel.ssdl|res://*/BF_sMaxModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=db;initial catalog=MM_BF_ENROLLMENTELIGIBILITY;user id=xxx;password=xxx;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Here is the ADO Connection I created to fix the one above:

```
 <add name="BF_sMaxEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/BF_sMaxModel.csdl|res://*/BF_sMaxModel.ssdl|res://*/BF_sMaxModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=R9TDXC5\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MM_BF_ENROLLMENTELIGIBILITY;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

The above works after I recreated the ADO Connection!!

Here is the original (when it was on their server) connection string for the non-working app:

```
 <add name="BF_sMaxEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/BF_sMaxModel.csdl|res://*/BF_sMaxModel.ssdl|res://*/BF_sMaxModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ias-SQLinst01;initial catalog=MM_BF_SoldCase;user id=xxx;password=xxx;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Here is the one I created:

```
<add name="BF_sMaxEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/BF_sMaxModel.csdl|res://*/BF_sMaxModel.ssdl|res://*/BF_sMaxModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=R9TDXC5\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MM_BF_SoldCase;user id=xxx;password=xxx;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I have copied the .sln, .suo, and the .edmx files from the project I created the new connections string for into the current non-working project.

I can connect to the non-working projects database using MSSMS, and a sql tool I use called "RAZOR"

I've checked the remote access to the database and all the obvious things... I've fairly new to VB but have been developing for over 20 years.

If there is anything I've not provided that will help to answer this... it's all yours, just ask.

Thanks In Advance!!!

BTW... I corrected my fat fingers... it is ADO

Comment: Your connection strings seem to be missing. Also, [DAO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984815%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is a long-dead COM-based technology. For .NET applications, you should be using ADO.NET instead.

Comment: OK, so you're using Entity Framework, not DAO. Are you getting any error messages? Can you connect to the database using the credentials from your connection string? *NB:* The working connection is using Windows auth; the non-working one is using SQL auth.

Answer (score 0):

The working connection is using Windows authentication. The one that's not working is using SQL authentication.

Unless you've explicitly configured your SQL Express instance to use mixed mode authentication, and set up the SQL user with the correct password and the correct permissions in the target database, SQL authentication won't work.

Try changing the non-working connection to use Windows authentication:

```
<add name="BF_sMaxEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/BF_sMaxModel.csdl|res://*/BF_sMaxModel.ssdl|res://*/BF_sMaxModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=R9TDXC5\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MM_BF_SoldCase;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```